# ReflectionMethod get method source and parameters

Tags: php, reflection, methods

I would like to have access to the methods by ReflectionMethod:

```
$r = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
$params = $r->getParameters();
```

and if parameters are required ($Option), get source of that method to prepare the parameters:

```
public function GetFeedback($Options) {
    $this->checkConnection();
    return $this->_client->doGetFeedback(
        $Options['feedback-from'],
        $Options['feedback-to']
    );
}
```

so in my example to find $Option keys - 'feedback-from' and 'feedback-to'

Comment: Curious why do you need that? o_O

Comment: I can call all the methods inside a class with jQuery, and if parameters are required open additional form to include them in request

Comment: It is not clear what actually you're doing there, but what is clear is that you're doing it terribly wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a class like

```
class Foo
{
    public function GetFeedback($Options) {
        $this->checkConnection();
        return $this->_client->doGetFeedback(
            $Options['feedback-from'],
            $Options['feedback-to']
        );
    }
}
```

this code will do what you ask for

```
$reflector = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'GetFeedback');
$methodBody = implode(
    '',
    iterator_to_array(
        new LimitIterator(
            new SplFileObject($reflector->getFileName()),
            $reflector->getStartLine(),
            $reflector->getEndLine() - $reflector->getStartLine()
        )
    )
);
foreach ($reflector->getParameters() as $parameter) {
    if (!$parameter->isOptional()) {
        preg_match_all(
            sprintf('{\$%s\[[\'"](.*)[\'"]\]}', $parameter->getName()),
            $methodBody,
            $matches
        );
    }
    print_r($matches);
}
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $Options['feedback-from']
            [1] => $Options['feedback-to']
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => feedback-from
            [1] => feedback-to
        )
)
```

However, the only valid usage for this approach IMO is to generate a docblock listing these options and agree that you are likely doing it wrong if you need this in production code.

Comment: new LimitIterator(
        new SplFileObject($reflector->getFileName()),
        $reflector->getStartLine(),
        $reflector->getEndLine() - $reflector->getStartLine()